# SQL Server : Foreign Key to Primary Key Left Join Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It seems that a lot of the time I am taking 5-15 minutes to LEFT Join tables that has a FK to PK relationship already.

Is there a way to create a procedure to return a table that left joins all the Tables that are connected to it through a foreign key?

Example

```
Exec getFKJoin(Some_Table)
```

1. Look for foreign keys on table
2. Iterate through each foreign key and find it's primary key counterpart (other_table)
3. `Some_Table left join other_table on Some_Table.FK = other_table.PK`
4. end iteration
5. Some_Table

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Note creating a PK, by default, creates a clustered index, and that improves finding matches in the PK (let's say in the parent table). But creating a FK in MS SQL don't. So the FK column (let's say in the child table) is not indexed. To solve slow running queries you ill must to check the actual execution plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the tables you need to query on each step so you can build on it and automate it in a stored procedure:

```
--Look for foreign keys on TABLE

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  -- query 1
WHERE constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY'
AND TABLE_NAME='Some_table'

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE -- query 2
WHERE constraint_name='Constraint_name_from_query_1' 


--Iterate through each foreign key and find it's primary key counterpart (other_table)

SELECT UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS -- query 3
WHERE constraint_name='Constraint_name_from_query_1'

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE -- query 4
WHERE constraint_name='Unique_constraint_from_query_3' 


-- Some_Table left join other_table on Some_Table.FK = other_table.PK

select * from table_name_from_query_2 LEFT JOIN table_name_from_query_4  ON column_name_from_query_2 = column_name_from_query_4
```